# how to apply mulpiple popovers backgrpund color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popover

I have a working code that displays a lot of features, and when I click on each feature, it'll show a popover, but I'd like to show it in different background colors, ex. there are three popovers displayed and each one with a different background color.

```
// display popup on click
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature) {
      return feature;
    });
  if (feature) {
    var element = document.getElementById(feature.get('name'));
    var popup = new Overlay({
      element: element,
      positioning: 'bottom-center',
      stopEvent: false,
      offset: [0, -15]
    });
    map.addOverlay(popup);

    var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    popup.setPosition(coordinates);
    $(element).popover({
      placement: 'top',
      html: true,
      content: feature.get('name')
    }); 
    $(element).popover('toggle');
    //$(".popover").css("background", "#C71F1F");   
  }
});
```

it is only using the ".popover", but I'd like to use the ".popover1" and ".popover2" using the JS code.

```
//CSS
.popover{
   background: #ebd997;
}
.popover1{
   background: #C71F1F;
}
.popover2{
   background: #FFE600;
}
```

Comment: This isn't enough information. What is the issue? When do you want the colors to change? also, you should use a secondary class for the background colors such as `.popover.blue` instead of `popoverblue`

Comment: the issue is that I don't know how to display 3 different popovers with 3 different background colors

Comment: You would just apply the different classes to them?

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to do it using javascript

Comment: sorry, I'm new in Js and CSS, this code I wrote is working, but it shows somo popover with the same style, I 'd like to show it with different styles

Comment: Use conditional statements to apply different classes to it than just the one

Comment: I 'm really sorry, I don't know hot to do that, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

I just solved, I created an new  and a new CSS Style, like this

```
var iDiv = document.createElement("div");
iDiv.id = "mydiv"+index;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
```

CSS

```
var css = '#' + iDiv.id + ' + .popover {background:#FFFFFF;}';
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
style = document.createElement('style');

head.appendChild(style);

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
// This is required for IE8 and below.
style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
```